# Detect a collision between a CharacterController and a 3D Object?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, character-controller

I am making an XR game, and I am stuck with a part. Does anyone know a function that would detect this?
`OnCollisionEnter` and `OnTriggerEnter` don't appear to work with a CharacterController. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnCollisionEnter` and `OnTriggerEnter` require both objects to have colliders and at least one of the objects to have a Rigidbody. You might also try `OnControllerColliderHit`, which is documented [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html).

Comment: Is there any other way of testing for a collision with a character controller?

Comment: You can look at `OnControllerColliderHit()`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html   You haven't provided any information about what you've already tried or how your objects are set up, so it's difficult to give more specific answers.